# SAPUI5 Use formatter inside formatter

Tags: javascript, sapui5, string-formatting

i am trying to access a formatter-method from another formatter-method, like this:

```
sap.ui.define(["<package>/model/formatter"], function(formatter) {
"use strict";

return {
    formatter: formatter,

    roundNumberToTwoDecimals: function(number) {
        if (number) {
            return number.toFixed(2);
        }
    },

    stringFormatter: function(sI18n, dNumber, sProduct) {
        var i18n = this.getModel("i18n");
        if (i18n) {
            return i18n.getText(sI18n, [formatter.roundNumberToTwoDecimals(dNumber), sProduct]);
        }
    }
};
```

However, my formatter (formatter.roundNumberToTwoDecimals) is undefined.
Does anyone know a solution to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define helper functions in private scope.

```
sap.ui.define(["<package>/model/formatter"], function() {
"use strict";

//private scope
var roundToDecimal = function(iNumber,iFixed){
   return iNumber.toFixed(iFixed);
}

return { 
    roundNumberToTwoDecimals: function(number) {
        if (number) {
            return roundToDecimal(number,2);
        }
    },

    stringFormatter: function(sI18n, dNumber, sProduct) {
        var i18n = this.getModel("i18n");
        if (i18n) {
            return i18n.getText(sI18n, [roundToDecimal(dNumber,2), sProduct]);
        }
    }
};
```

The function roundToDecimal can be accessed only by the functions within the formatter. It can't be accessed directly as a formatter function from a view as it's not supposed to be exposed as a formatter function but just a helper function. With this way, the context of 'this' passed to the formatter doesn't matter as it changes from jsview to xml view.

Answer (score 3):

```
this.formatter.roundNumberToTwoDecimals(dNumber);
```

works fine (this is the controller of the view)

Answer (score 0):

try this.roundNumberToTwoDecimals(dNumber)

Comment: with this you get the controller of the xml-view